# file handling in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, large-files

I have a large text file almost 150 MB to 500 MB and this file contains 20 lacs lines...

Contents of the file goes like this....

```
USDINR12AUGFUT           1  1343791803  579782   2012-08-01 09:00:03  BID          55.5725       200
USDINR12AUGFUT           2  1343791803  594246   2012-08-01 09:00:03  BID          55.9650       150
USDINR12AUGFUT           3  1343791803  594570   2012-08-01 09:00:03  ASK          56.0700       100
USDINR12AUGFUT           4  1343791803  946831   2012-08-01 09:00:03  ASK          56.0450       500
USDINR12AUGFUT           5  1343791804   16514   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        55.9650         5  55965.00         5
USDINR12AUGFUT           6  1343791804   19401   2012-08-01 09:00:04  BID          55.9800        14
USDINR12AUGFUT           7  1343791804   32311   2012-08-01 09:00:04  BID          56.0000       100
USDINR12AUGFUT           8  1343791804   33292   2012-08-01 09:00:04  ASK          56.0400       150
USDINR12AUGFUT           9  1343791804   34695   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55970.83         6
USDINR12AUGFUT          10  1343791804   35599   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55975.00         7
USDINR12AUGFUT          11  1343791804   36626   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55978.12         8
USDINR12AUGFUT          12  1343791804   53676   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000        60  55997.43        68
USDINR12AUGFUT          13  1343791804   57434   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000        25  55998.12        93
USDINR12AUGFUT          14  1343791804   57967   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.14        94
USDINR12AUGFUT          15  1343791804   60474   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.16        95
USDINR12AUGFUT          16  1343791804   60988   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.18        96
USDINR12AUGFUT          17  1343791804   61232   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.20        97
USDINR12AUGFUT          18  1343791804   61974   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.21        98
USDINR12AUGFUT          19  1343791804   62449   2012-08-01 09:00:04  TRADE        56.0000         1  55998.23        99
```

my question is i want to do some back test on MATLAB using this file, so i have to import this file. But whenever i use `fopen` and `textscan` MATLAB throws an error saying ...

```
??? Error using ==> textscan
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

but when i use 20-50 MB file it runs fine.

How to overcome with this? help me out...

---

My Code:

```
% file_path = 'E:\volume\august\AUG03.MCX';
file_path = 'D:\home\flexsys\pavan\usdinr_t\USDINR12AUGFUT.MCX';

fid = fopen(file_path);

C = textscan(fid,'%s %d %d %d %s %s %s %f %d %f %d');
n = length(C{1});

for i = 1 : n
    raw_data.symbol(i)      = C{1}(i);
    raw_data.trade_no(i)    = C{2}(i);
    raw_data.utc_sec(i)     = C{3}(i);
    raw_data.utc_nano(i)    = C{4}(i);
    raw_data.date(i)        = C{5}(i);
    raw_data.time(i)        = C{6}(i);
    raw_data.trade_type(i)  = C{7}(i);
    raw_data.ltp(i)         = C{8}(i);
    raw_data.ltq(i)         = C{9}(i);
    raw_data.vwap(i)        = C{10}(i);
    raw_data.volume(i)      = C{11}(i);

    % % % some back testing here.

end
```

i had stored all the data in `C` variable and there goes the error

Comment: do you need all the data at once? if not, and the data is too large to fit in memory, you could read it by lines and process each one-at-a-time

Comment: what i am doing is i am reading all the data in one variable then i am finding averages based on 60 values of ltp and so on....so how can i process this line by line ...in some functions i need data of 60 lines in some 200 lines and so on...because i am taking only TRADE lines from a file.

Comment: textscan does support a `N` argument that specifies number of times format string is applied: `textscan(fid, frmt, 60)`. Next time it is called, it continues where it left off..

Comment: actually i am passing this raw data to 20-25 functions at a time

Comment: the idea is read the data in batches of whatever size you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run out of memory, you have to do something to use less memory. There are some good ideas in the other answers here, but if those fail the only thing left is to read and process the file in chunks that can fit into memory.

One option is to call `textscan` with a parameter `N` that specifies how many times to read the `format` you specify. Put that call in a loop and it will read a chunk of the file every time. Something like this:

```
while ~feof(fid)
    C = textscan(fid, 'format', N);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works here, but how about using a higher level command to read in the data?

Given your data structure I would look into `csvread`, `xlsread` or `dlmread`.

Also you can *rightclick* on the file when it is in the current folder and click on `import`.

Comment: actually the lines in a file is creating problems almost 10 to 20 lacs of lines...you cant import using csvread xlsread...i had tried all...i have to check for dlmread....

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the number of rows or a repeat format number with `textscan`, MATLAB calculates the exact amount of memory required beforehand.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html

Comment: % file_path = 'E:\volume\august\AUG03.MCX';
file_path = 'D:\home\flexsys\pavan\usdinr_t\USDINR12AUGFUT.MCX';


block_size = 1000;

format = '%s %d %d %d %s %s %s %f %d %f %d';

fid = fopen(file_path);

while ~feof(fid)
   
    C = textscan(fid, format,bolck_size);   
   
end....the problem is that this code is taking only last block_size lines...i am not understanding it should take first or last